Where does the COM of a bungee jumper lie?
I came across the following problem in one of the books i was solving,

In bungee jumping, a performer ties on end of an elastic cord with his feet and the other end to a fixed support on a very high place and then jumps off. A bungee jumper of height $h = 1.5\hspace{1mm}m$, and mass $m = 66\hspace{1mm}kg$ has to jump from a tower of height $H = 62.5\hspace{1mm}m$. The Bungee cord available is $\_0 = 30\hspace{1mm}m$ long and has a force constant $k = 33\hspace{1mm}N/m$. If the minimum safe clearance from the ground is $d = 1\hspace{1mm}m$, what is the maximum length of this cord can the bungee jumper use?

I tried solving this problem multiple times but could not get the write answer when i looked at the solution i observed that it had been solved by assuming that the COM of a bungee jumper is at their feet and then applying energy conservation.
Is their a reason for why the COM of a bungee jumper is at their feet or is this an assumption required to solve the problem, the answer to the question was given to be 20 m.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

I don't think the position of the COM of the jumper is important. The unstated assumption in the question is that the bungee cord is tied to the feet of the bungee jumper. So if we subtract the $1$ metre minimum safe clearance and the jumper's height of $1.5$ metres from the tower height of $62.5$ metres, you get a maximum extended length for the rope, which is $60$ metres.
However, I think there is another problem with the given answer - it seems to assume that the jumper's speed when the rope is at its unextended length of $20$ metres is zero, so the jumper will execute SHM with an amplitude of $20$ metres about the rope's equilibrium length of $40$ metres. However, if the rope is attached to the top of the tower, and the jumper jumps from the top of the tower too, then this assumption is incorrect.
